# RxJava zip to combine api calls

Tags: android, retrofit, observable, rx-java2

I am trying to make parallel calls to an api using the Observable.zip. Each of those api calls returns an Observable>. I am creating a list of observables and sending that list to the zip together with a function that returns Observable> made out of the individual Observable> that are returned by those api calls. For some reasons the object[] is initialized with 20 items of TreeSet which is fine, but each TreeSet is empty, although in the logs I can spot the response for the api calls contain data.

```
subscription = repository
            .getFollowers(id, OFFSET)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(FollowerResponse::getCollection)
            .flatMap((Function<List<Follower>, Observable<TreeSet<Track>>>) followers -> {
                List<Observable<TreeSet<Track>>> list = new ArrayList<>();
                observable = repository.getTracks(OFFSET, String.valueOf(followers.get(0).getId()));
                list.add(observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty()));
                for (int i = 1; i < followers.size(); i++) {
                    observable = Observable.merge(observable, repository.getTracks(OFFSET, String.valueOf(followers.get(i).getId())));

                    list.add(observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty()));
                }

                return Observable.zip(list, new Function<Object[], TreeSet<Track>>() {
                    @Override
                    public TreeSet<Track> apply(Object[] objects) throws Exception {
                        TreeSet<Track> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();
                        Log.e("zip ", "inside zip");
                        for (Object obj : objects) {
                            treeSet.addAll((TreeSet<Track>) obj);
                        }
                        return treeSet;
                    }

                });
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<TreeSet<Track>>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(TreeSet<Track> tracks) throws Exception {
                    Log.e("zip ", "inside subscribe");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

damn, I just realized I did not remove the Observable.merge I was trying ou before the Observable.zip! Really helps posting, it's like thinking out loud lol